# QtQuick.Controls 2.0 How to change handle position in Slider when it pressed?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquickcontrols2

In QtQuick.Controls 1 if you press somewhere on the Slider the handle will move immediately there. But in QtQuick.Controls 2 this behaviour is different, the handle moves only if you **press** and **move** a mouse.

How can I get the behaviour similar to the QtQuick.Controls 1 Slider?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply [this change](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/162200/) to your Qt build, or wait for the 5.7.1 release.